# Titanium Studio: Modifying a Titanium imageview through an Android module

Tags: android, module, imageview, titanium

I am very new to Titanium and I am trying to understand how I can modify a Titanium imageview through an Android module. Specifically, I have created a method in the Android module that creates an Android imageview, draws a blue circle and sets the imageview to contain the blue circle. The original Titanium imageview contains an image. I want to change the image to the blue circle on a singletap event. Can someone explain how I might be able to do this? I know how to create the module and how to detect the singletap event. I just don't know how I can use the imageview I created in the Android module in my index.js (I want to display the blue circle in the index window).

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the code in that link is for iOS; I'm trying to get this to work for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer thanks to Michael G on [my other post](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/161901/modifying-a-titanium-imageview-through-an-android-module#comment-201327)